# Software & Updates (software-properties-gtk): 'EOFError: marshal data too short'

Tags: apt, python, update-manager, system-settings, gnupg

I cannot open Software & Updates tool on 14.04 and get the following error:

[image]

Here is the [full output of `apt-get update`](http://pastebin.com/8a9AXujX), it shows this warning:

```
W: GPG error: http://dl.bintray.com  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 99E82A75642AC823
```

When I run `sudo software-properties-gtk`, I get [this error traceback](http://pastebin.com/NkRynvmZ). It shows errors like `EOFError: marshal data too short`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Give the terminal output of `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Here is what sudo apt-get update gives:

http://pastebin.com/8a9AXujX

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Comment: @ByteCommander No, the solutions at the post didn't work.

Comment: @yildizabdullah [Removing](http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-remove-ppa-include-installed-packages-in-ubuntu) the bintray ppa would do.

Comment: @reversiblean deleted /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list file which includes the address of the repo. still getting the same error after apt-get update and restart.

Comment: @ByteCommander I've noticed that I cannot run `sudo software-properties-gtk` http://pastebin.com/NkRynvmZ

Comment: You are not supposed to run `software-properties-gtk` with `sudo`! Launch it as your normal user account and it will ask for privilege elevation when needed itself. - And please try if the problem gets solved after you run `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* ; sudo apt-get update`. Did that help?

Comment: @ByteCommander No, it didn't work. Running `software-properties-gtk` without `sudo` gives similar errors I got before.

Comment: @yildizabdullah Please run `sudo updatedb ; locate '*.pyc' ; locate '*.pyo'` and upload the output to another pastebin.

Comment: And which Python 2 (`python --version`) and Python 3 (`python3 --version`) version do you use, what is used to run the Software&Updates tool (`head -n 1 $(which software-properties-gtk)`)? Please give the output of all of those commands.

Comment: @ByteCommander Here is what `locate '*.pyc'` outputs: http://pastebin.com/iSR1a6mv (`locate '*.pyo'` didn't output anything)

Comment: @ByteCommander `python --version` outputs `Python 2.7.6` and `python3 --version` outputs `Python 3.4.3`. `head -n 1 $(which software-properties-gtk)` outputs `#! /usr/bin/python3`

Comment: @yildizabdullah Please run `sudo rm -r /usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/__pycache__` and then try to launch `software-properties-gtk` (without `sudo`!) again.

Comment: @ByteCommander OK. It worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @yildizabdullah I converted my comments into an answer. Please accept it by clicking the grey tick symbol on its left side to mark your question as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

- GPG missing key error on the `http://dl.bintray.com` repository
- `EOFError: marshal data too short` when Python3 tries to `import urllib` to launch `software-properties-gtk` (the "Software & Updates" settings window)

---

To resolve the GPG error, please follow *@[GAD3R](https://askubuntu.com/users/498780/gad3r)*'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/736275/367990) or any answer to [How do I fix the GPG error "NO_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

You decided to remove this repository from your software sources, which is also ok if you don't need it any more.

---

To resolve the Python EOFError, we need to eliminate some `*.pyc` files. Those are compiled byte code of a script, which gets dynamically created when a Python script runs to speed up future launches. They are faulty and don't match the original script any more for whatever reason. We can simply delete them as they are not really needed and will be recreated on the next launch.

We don't want a massacre but a small and effective removal of the faulty files only. Therefore we look at the error traceback from the `software-properties-gtk` output and find out that this error always happens when Python 3.4 tries to `import urllib.parse`. To avoid follow-up errors we simply remove all `*.pyc` files related to Python 3.4's urllib module:

```
sudo rm -r /usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/__pycache__
```

Answer (score 0):

Type the following command :

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 99E82A75642AC823
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: I eliminated this error by first removing the related repo address at `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list` and then running `sudo apt-get update`.